# DataGridView: can you add an unbound column to a Data Bound grid?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, datagridview

I´m using Visual Studio 2008, C#

**DataGridView: can you add an unbound column to a Data Bound grid?**

It seems pretty simple, just select the properties ("DataGridView Tasks box") for the data bound DataGridView, and select Add unbound column.
However, when in runtime there will be a System.FormatException - which I can understand, as I don´t know how to "initialize" the cells in the new unbound columns.

I was planning initializing it programmatically via CellFormatting event - but so far I´m failing.

Any tips? Just want to get it up and running in SOME way...

Answer (score 0):

What type of data formatting would you like to have? And what is the value **Type** you would like to add to that column?

Maybe this can help:

In the **Designer** -> **Edit Columns...** if you select your new unbound column you have an **Appearance** section.

If you click to **DefaultCellStyle** inside you can find, under **Behavior**, the **Format** property. From there, you can choose the **Format** for your column.